# Attempted to call function "split" from namespace "Controller"

Tags: php, silex

I want to call php method `split` in my controller

```
var_dump(split(' ',getimagesize($file)[3]));
```

but it gives this problem

[image]

My controller's namespace is "Controller", i don't know why it tries to call "split" from it.
pleaze help, and thanks!

Comment: Because you're in the namespace `Controller`, so PHP tries to call `Controller/split`, PHP-core functions are in the global namespace, so you have to call them with a backslash. `\split(...);`

Comment: What php version do you use?

Comment: firstly thanks for your response, i already tried that and i had this problemme "Attempted to call function "split" from the global namespace."
still not working

Comment: i am using php5.6.25

Comment: Try replace `split` with `explode`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Split`](http://php.net/split) function is deprecated and has been removed since php7.

So, trying to call `split('something')` means that php looks not for global `split` function which not exists already, but for your custom `split` function in a certain namespace. Obviously, you don't define `split` in your namespace. As a result - function `split` is **not found**.

The solution is to use more up-to-date function, in this case it is `explode` or `preg_split`.

Comment: The 1-to-1 replacement for `split` is `preg_split`.

Comment: If there's no regexps - `explode` is enough. But thanks, added to my answer.

Comment: In my case same problem with `json_encode` was resolved by installing `php7-json` extension